# Possible to use tint color for a customview based UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible to color cutomview based `UIBarButtonItem` like normal `UIBarButtonItem`?

```
UIBarButtonItem *update = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:b];
```

Or is it know which tint color is the default?

Should I recolor the image with standard tint color (0, 122, 255)?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your custom view?

Comment: attached the image below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your image like this:

```
UIImage(named: "imagename")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

You can also set `Render As` to `Template Image` in the asset catalog instead.

Comment: You're welcome. If your "custom view" is just an image though you can use the `convenience init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: Any?, action: Selector?)` initializer. In that case the image should automatically get tinted without any explicit setting.